Blazor (or vanilla C#) to WASM for showing a console application on a webpage
"That's odd. Why are you doing this?" I just want to know if it's possible. Of course there's alternatives, as there is to everything. This is 100% just a proof of concept.
I have a simple page with some console code in my Blazor project:
@page "/run-console"
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="RunConsoleApp">Run Console App</button>

@code
{
    private async Task RunConsoleApp()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tell me something you've never told anyone before: ");
        string answer = Console.ReadLine() ?? "You can't handle it";
        Console.WriteLine("Really? \"" + answer + "\"?");
        Console.ReadKey();
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Console App Running");
    }
}

@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<main>
    @Body
</main>

<div id="run-console"></div>

I also have this Angular (because that's what I'm familiar with) component meant to house this interaction. The proposed solution can be in any framework or even a plain HTML page. Anyway, after running dotnet build and copying the _framework directory to src/assets:
<div id="app">
  Loading...
</div>

import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';

declare var Blazor: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-console',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './console.component.html',
  styleUrl: './console.component.scss'
})
export class ConsoleComponent {
  private static blazorStarted = false;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId) && !ConsoleComponent.blazorStarted) {
      this.initializeBlazor();
    }
  }

  private initializeBlazor() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'assets/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js';
    script.onload = () => {
      if (!ConsoleComponent.blazorStarted) {
        ConsoleComponent.blazorStarted = true;
        Blazor.start({
          loadBootResource: (type: string, name: string, defaultUri: string, integrity: string) => {
            return `/${name}`;
          }
        });
      }
    };
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(script);
  }
}

I think this is on the right track solely for the weak reason that it executes. The problems are the WriteLine statements go to the browser's console and the ReadLine statement crashes it because the browser doesn't support it.
Is it at all possible to show the entire console and have it behave the same on the webpage the way it would when running on desktop?
